# Best approach to tab based web browsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs

What's the best approach for tab based browsing? Pros and cons for each one?

I'm trying to implement a page where all navigation is tab based; I want a type of side-menu/drawer, along with a header on top (a simple bar for a logo) and then have the remaining part of the screen be the container which will be filled depending on the item(tab) selected.

I can set it all up, but how do I effectively load each different page within that content view?  I quickly tried hiding/showing each according `<div>` with jQuery, but it kinda brought up an issue with google maps and the other js libraries I was using.

Also tried `load()`, but I remember it giving me some trouble also. Should it all be contained in one page, or different pages and just load each page to that `<div>`(frames? don't know mucha about'em)?

Comment: If you load everything all at once, just hiding and showing the necessary containers, you will be suffering a hit in load time. There is no reason to load everything all at once. I would suggest using some sort of AJAX setup, where you load the tab content once it is requested.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone will have their preference for how to create a single page app.  I'm using angularjs, because I want the two-way binding filter capabilities for my data.  One way angularjs controls the adding and removing of pages is with `ng-view`

```
<div ng-view id='ChgViewSection'></div>
```

That `<div>` is empty.  The content gets added or removed by changing the URL, (Without reloading the page) which then triggers some code.  The code has something called `$routeProvider`, and the routing specifies the content to put into the DIV element.

I change the URL with: `window.location.href`

```
function mainMenuChg(argPage) {
  //console.log('argPage: ' + argPage);

  window.location.href = "#" + argPage;
};
```

To create your own page routing, without any framework, you would need a way to retrieve HTML content from a file.  You could put all the content in one HTML file and then hide and show sections, but that will be get confusing, trying to figure out what HTML goes to what page.  So, you need a way to separate each page into it's own file, then retrieve the content.

Changing the URL at the same time you change the page, allows the user to share a link to a specific page.  So, if you want users to be able to promote specific page content, that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks! This was my initial thought, and believe-it-or-not, I was about to start doing Code School's AngularJS course cause I thought it'd help solve the problem. Good to know I was on-track.